# Returning an array. Not understanding how arrays are returned

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm getting kind of confused looking at this code. When it says "return result" I end up getting back just one number. What is it doing? It ends up printing 2 and 4 in the console. I also don't understand why [0] and [1] are specified when the array is passed into the method.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}};
    System.out.println(m1(array)[0]);
    System.out.println(m1(array)[1]);
  }

  public static int[] m1(int[][] m) {
    int[] result = new int[2];
    result[0] = m.length;
    result[1] = m[0].length;
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `m1(array)[0]` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: I'm quite unsure, when I walk through debugger it shows the same array getting passed into the method both times. There's no difference whether it's [0] or [1], it just passes the whole 2d array

Comment: Ok let me make it more clear. What does the  `[0]`  do in that expression?

Comment: I believe it accesses the 0th element of the 2d array (1, 2, 3, 4), which would just be a 1d array. But if the method takes a 2d array as a parameter, something is not right?

Comment: The expression `m1(array)` invokes the `m1` method passing the value of `array` as an argument. Your `m1` method then returns a `int[]` value. You use `[0]` to access its first element so your `println` only prints that one value.

Comment: Ooooh it's not part of passing the parameter it's just getting the 0th from whatever is returned. Ohhh

Comment: I get it now, thank you!

Comment: Don't look at the code as a whole, first think line by line. And you will know almost everything.

Comment: Yes, I think that's a mistake I keep doing. I have to think like a computer haha